# Custom NSButton and NSButtonCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I'm trying to create a custom button look.

From what I've gathered, `NSButtonCell` does the drawing, so I should actually be overwriting that instead.

But the issue is, my CustomButton class has other things like `NSImage`, `mIsMouseOver` etc. Currently the drawing is being done in the CustomButton class but I want to move it over to the cell.

question is, is there anyway I can access the image in the customButton class from the customButtonCell class so that I may use `[image drawInRect:...]`?

Regards,
Han

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell's `drawWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView` method includes a reference to the NSView being drawn from which you can access the view's properties (such as image).

Comment: I think that sounds like a plan, I'll give that a shot. It was all working fine till I layer backed my view and all my custom buttons don't work, thus I have to rewrite all to draw in cell instead of the button :(

Answer (score 1):

Usual way is to store the data in the NSCell subclass. Base cell class even has an -(id)image property, so, your button class should call `[[self cell] image]` when it is queried for image.

Actually, since you are subclassing NSButton, it contains all you need, just override cell's drawing methods. And if you need an extra property - define it in the cell, wrap in the control.